# When to use UFUNCTION for delegates

Tags: delegates, unreal-engine4

In UnrealEngine, [`UFUNCTION`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Reference/Functions) is used for enriching functions with additional specifiers for blueprint usage, replication and delegates.

However, some delegate types don't seem to allow to bind a `UFUNCTION` (like a multicast delegate), while other types require to bind a `UFUNCTION` (like a dynamic multicast delegate).

Is there an overview available, what delegate type accepts which type of function (normal c++ or `UFUNCTION`)?

Answer (score 8):

Only [**dynamic**](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Delegates/Dynamic) [delegates](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Delegates) require the functions which can be bounded to be a [`UFUNCTION`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Reference/Functions).

```
+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| Type                                          |  binds c++ function  |  binds `UFUNCTION` |
+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| Singlecast                                    |  yes                 |  yes               |
| Multicast                                     |  yes                 |  no                |
| Event                                         |  yes                 |  ?                 |
| Dynamic singlecast                            |  no                  |  yes               |
| Dynamic multicast                             |  no                  |  yes               |
| `FTimerDelegate` (singlecast)                 |  yes                 |  yes               |
| `FTimerDynamicDelegate` (dynamic singlecast)  |  no                  |  yes               |
+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
```

(This is my observation so far. In case of errors, please comment or edit or add an answer.)

#### Performance

`UFUNCTION` increases compile time and artifact size, so only use the macro when required by the calling code.

Dynamic delegates support serializing, have additional code for working in Blueprint graphs (called Events/Event Dispatcher in BP) and are slower than the other delegate types. If you only need delegates for C++, you don’t need dynamic ones most of the time.

#### C++ template support for non dynamic delegates

Delegates which accepts binding of c++ functions, can be wrapped by a template

```
template<typename T>
struct MyTemplateWrapper
{
    DECLARE_MULTICAST_DELEGATE_OneParam(FMyDelegateWithTemplate, T);
};
```

Use it like `MyTemplateWrapper<float>::FMyDelegateWithTemplate MyCallback;`.

Keep in mind: The `UPROPERTY` macro is not supported for `MyCallback` since `MyTemplateWrapper` can't be a `USTRUCT`/`UCLASS` (since they don’t support templates). However, because the *non* dynamic delegate types don't support blueprints nevertheless, the missing `UPROPERTY` is not a loss.

#### Off topic: Additional usage of `UFUNCTION`

Short summary at [unreal answers](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/129550/when-to-use-ufunction-macro.html).